# SXA Scriban Dynamic Placeholders

Tags: sxa, scriban, dynamic-placeholder

I am trying to render a dynamic placeholder with the Scriban as follows:

`{{ sc_placeholder 'section' }}`

and I would expect it to add a number to the key i.e. **section-3**, etc, but this is what I see as a result:
[image]

which is not what I expected.

P.s. I have the `IsRenderingsWithDynamicPlaceholders` property set to `true` on my rendering item.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I could be wrong, it is only an assumption, but I think that your Scriban template doesn't know anything about parental controls in the rendering runtime. (Otherwise, performance will be poor). That is why SXA thinks that it is the first placeholder section in this context and doesn't add the dynamic suffix.

Comment: @Anton thank you. for now I will just create a .cshtml rendering, but let's keep the question open in case anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using asterix at the end of your placeholder key in Scriban will solve your issue. (It works well in SXA 10.1)

```
{{ sc_placeholder "myplaceholderkey*" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was finding that using the wildcard naming convention (with the * ) did not work with Sitecore 9.3. I suspect they added support for using the wildcard convention in Sitecore 10.

If you are on Sitecore 9.3, an alternative is to roll your own dynamic placeholder logic. Taking a cue from how SXA does it, you can leverage the value of the DynamicPlaceholderId rendering parameter. For example:

```
{{ dynamic_placeholder_id = sc_parameter "DynamicPlaceholderId" }}
{{ sc_placeholder "NameOfThePlaceholder-" + dynamic_placeholder_id }}
```

You could also take this a step further and write your own custom Scriban extension that leverages the same DynamicPlaceholderId value and then you could call it like this:

```
{{ sc_dynamic_placeholder "NameOfThePlaceholder" }}
```

Comment: I have found that there is a Sitecore patch/fix/package for this to allow for the wildcard syntax to work in 9.3. The package name is: SC Hotfix 394455-1 SXA 9.3.0.2589

Answer (score 0):

Use the asterisk sign at the end of the placeholder name: Ex.

`{{ sc_placeholder "NameofthePlaceholder*" }}`

and it will add no to the key like this `NameofthePlaceholder-1-1`